# PaperTrail: info_for_paper_trail outside the context of a controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, versioning, delayed-job, paper-trail-gem

I am using the [paper_trail](https://github.com/airblade/paper_trail) gem for versioning my models.

So far, my model depends on the `info_for_paper_trail` method in `ApplicationController`:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  # Extra columns to store along with PaperTrail `versions`
  def info_for_paper_trail
    { revision_id: @revision.id, revision_source_id: @revision_source.id }
  end
end
```

**This works great in context of the controller, but is there a way that I can replicate this sort of thing outside the context of the controller (e.g., a delayed job)?**

I tried creating a virtual attribute called `revision` and passing a `proc` into `has_paper_trail`, but it errors out with a `method not found` exception:

```
# Attempt to solve this in the model
class Resource < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Virtual attribute
  attr_accessor :revision

  # Attempt to use virtual attribute only if set from delayed job
  has_paper_trail meta: proc { |resource| resource.revision.present? ? { revision_id: resource.revision.id, revision_source_id: revision.revision_source.id } : {} }
end

# Gist of what I'm trying to do in the delayed job
resource = Resource.new
resource.revision = Revision.new(user: user, revision_source: revision_source)
resource.save!
```

I assume based on this result that `meta` cannot take a `proc`, and plus I don't like how this solution smells anyway...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to set these values in your code if you're operating outside of the controller:

```
::PaperTrail.controller_info = { revision_id: revision.id, revision_source_id: revision_source.id }
::PaperTrail.whodunnit = user.id
```

The model will then pick the extra values up just like it would normally from the controller.

I derived this info from looking at the [`PaperTrail::Controller`](https://github.com/airblade/paper_trail/blob/9da4930ab5d786c5fb8fec33a0d270eed1b2ca55/lib/paper_trail/controller.rb) module. Particularly, look at the `set_paper_trail_controller_info` and `set_paper_trail_whodunnit` methods that get run as before filters.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can just do:

```
class Resource < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Virtual attribute
  attr_accessor :revision, :revision_source

  # Attempt to use virtual attribute only if set from delayed job
  has_paper_trail meta: { 
    revision_id: :get_revision_id, 
    revision_source_id: get_revision_source.id 
  }

  def get_revision_id
    resource.revision.try(:id)
  end

  def get_revision_source_id
    resource.revision_source.try(:id)
  end
end
```