# Ruby: Execute method in context of base class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, paper-trail-gem, rails-activejob

I have about 20 different [Active Jobs](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_job_basics.html) which I now realise are each going to need a `before_perform` method in which to set [PaperTrail content outside the context of the controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17970490/papertrail-info-for-paper-trail-outside-the-context-of-a-controller).

I was planning on putting this `before_perform` method in a helper and then including the helper in each of the jobs but I am getting an error:

> undefined method `before_perform' for MyApp:JobHelpers:Module

I am thinking that this is because the module in question is just that, a module and not an Active Job. How can I avoid repeating the same 4 line `before_perform` method in each of my Active Jobs?

**Job_helper:**

```
module MyApp
  module JobHelpers
    before_perform do |job|
      # stuff to do
    end
  end
end
```

**The_job:**

```
require 'my_app/job_helpers'

class TheJob < ActiveJob::Base
  include MyApp::JobHelpers

 # Do more stuff
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used an [`included` callback](https://rubymonk.com/learning/books/4-ruby-primer-ascent/chapters/48-advanced-modules/lessons/117-included-and-extend) to achieve my desired goal. I found a better description of the included callback than I could ever give in another answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5160822/1945948).

While other answers were similar, please find the solution that worked for me below:

```
module MyApp
  module JobHelpers
    def self.included(job_class)
      job_class.before_perform do |job|
        # work to be completed  
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 3):

Rewrite your helper like this:

```
module MyApp
  module JobHelpers
    extend ActiveSupport::Concern

    included do

      # inside this you can call ActiveJob helpers
      before_perform do
        # stuff to do
      end
    end
  end
end
```